# How to prevent Method calls from Unknown addins

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I have a core set of libs(framework) built on top of prism and it loads other modules built by other 3rd parties which should use the "recommended" approach but there's no inbuilt mechanism ( as far as i can tell ) to prevent any 3rd party code to use methods which are meant for internal/core use only.

Is there a pattern to check for assembly of the calling code and verify it to contain some known signature perhaps ?

This is for prism but i suppose would apply to any DI/IoC framework where certain methods are internal only

Comment: You may want to consider using a different container for your 3rd party addins; this way your plugins can't import internal services, as your plugin container won't be configured to provide them.  This assumes, of course, that you're splitting up internal services into their own classes (or at least interfaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods for internal use should be marked internal, and therefore invisible to the third-party callers.  If you need to share methods across your own assemblies, use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.

**EDIT**

To make members unavailable to third-party assemblies, **mark the members *internal***.  This prohibits access by third-party assemblies.  I mentioned the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` because of the possibility that

- your internal code comprises more than one assembly
- you have marked some members public to provide inter-assembly access, but you don't want third-party code to have access to these members.

Example:

code for MyAssemblyA:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    //this method is public because I want to be able to use it in MyAssemblyB
    public static void SomeMethodThatShouldBeInternal()
    {

    }
}
```

code for my MyAssemblyB:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SomeClass.SomeMethodThatShouldBeInternal();
    }
}
```

To prevent third-party code from having access to `SomeMethodThatShouldBeInternal()`, change the declaration:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    internal static void SomeMethodThatShouldBeInternal()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, MyAssemblyB will not compile!  However, you can fix that by adding this attribyute to MyAssemblyA:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssemblyB")]
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what is asked, excerpt - Specifies that types that are ordinarily visible only within the current assembly are visible to a specified assembly.
From here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: @Kumar I mentioned `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` in case you made your members public for internal access.  See edited answer for details.

Comment: oh i see, that might work except for DI via MEF, will look into it, thx